# How close to zero mV and mA can I get out of this circuit? Is open circuit involved?

Tags: arduino, voltage, operational-amplifier, schematics, current-measurement

Given this schematic:

[image]

and this code:

[image]

and these results:

[image]

How close to zero mV and mA should I expect this circuit to get? Is the fact that there is no load on the circuit, that it's open, effecting it? If the scale factor is removed it is much closer but still -2.499mA.

Thanks
Tim

[image]

How about this. I just made it out of two symbols in KiCAD.

[image]

Comment: How are you measuring your voltage and current?

Comment: You've forgotten to connect power to your opamp (pin-8), and *please* use standard symbols for standard components. A generic block with pins laid out like the physical part doesn't make your schematic easy to read.

Comment: Vout is calculated as part of the current calculation. Vin is calculated by other code that I did not include.

Comment: @brhans The way that the chip is wired follows the datasheet. I will use standard symbols when I can find them.

Comment: You can't find a symbol for an opamp? Really? And in your schematic your opamp's pin-8 is connected to nothing other than a capacitor. It has no power supply.

Comment: @brhans I added the schematic from the datasheet. How would I display a 2 channel op amp using the standard symbol?

Comment: The schematic from the datasheet shows pin-8 connected to "V+", which your schematic does not have. My schematic editor has 1000's of different opamps to choose from - I would just pick something generic like a TL072 or LM358 if yours doesn't have a generic "dual opamp" - the pinouts are almost all the same.